# Question in My Son's Math Training Worksheet that Has Me Completely Baffled

Tags: contest-math

I am not sure what title to put as the question really has both me and my son confused.  It says this:

"If PLUS equals 68, what does MINUS equal?"

and the choices are:

A. 102  B. 76  C. 120  D. 46

and the answer provided in the answer key was 76.

Maybe someone here has encountered some problem with a similar logic?  We are utterly confused at where to start with the solution and have tried researching about inverse, etc.

Hoping someone can help with this.  Thanks :)

Comment: Let $A=1$, $B=2$,...,$Z=26$. Now add the letters of each together. You will get:
$$PLUS\implies P+L+U+S=16+12+21+19=68$$
$$MINUS\implies M+I+N+U+S=13+9+14+21+19=76$$

Comment: The most baffling thing is why anyone would call this "math training".

Comment: It's a bit like calling crosswords "author training".

Comment: Thanks everyone for your quick replies. It is amazing how helpful everyone in this community is :)  @rschwieb: I completely agree.  And the funny thing is I just found out that the person who gave this "training material" got this from a Math Olympiad book which is currently being sold lol

Answer (score 1):

Sum up the positions of the letters in the alphabet beginning with

- $A = 1 \Rightarrow$
  $$PLUS = P+L+U+S = 16+12+19+21=68$$

Comment: OMG thank you so much for answering this.  I guess we have been too concentrated on numbers and solving stuff that this completely flew by.